# What is loss_cls and loss_bbox and why are they always zero in training

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, object-detection

I'm trying to train a custom dataset on using `faster_rcnn` using the Pytorch implementation of Detectron [here](https://github.com/roytseng-tw/Detectron.pytorch). I have made changes to the dataset and configuration according to the guidelines in the repo.

The training process is carried out successfully, but the `loss_cls` and `loss_bbox` values are 0 from the beginning and even though the training is completed, final output cannot be used to make an evaluation or an inference.
I would like to know what these two mean and how to get those values to change during the training. The exact model I'm using here is `e2e_faster_rcnn_R-50-FPN_1x`

Any help regarding this would be appreciated. I' using Ubuntu 16.04 with Python 3.6 on Anaconda, CUDA 9, cuDNN 7.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

##### What are the two losses?

When training a multi-object detector, you usually have (at least) two types of losses:

1. `loss_bbox`: a loss that measures how "tight" the predicted bounding boxes are to the ground truth object (usually a regression loss, `L1`, `smoothL1` etc.).
2. `loss_cls`: a loss that measures the correctness of the *classification* of each predicted bounding box: each box may contain an object class, or a "background". This loss is usually called cross entropy loss.

##### Why are the losses always zero?

When training a detector, the model predict quite a few (~1K) possible boxes per image. Most of them are empty (i.e. belongs to "background" class). The loss function associate each of the predicted boxes with the ground truth boxes annotation of the image.

If a predicted box has a significant overlap with a ground truth box then `loss_bbox` and `loss_cls` are computed to see how well the model is able to predict the ground truth box.

On the other hand, if a predicted box has no overlap with any ground truth box, than only `loss_cls` is computed for the "background" class.
However, if there is only very partial overlap with ground truth the predicted box is "discarded" and no loss is computed. I suspect, for some reason, this is the case for your training session.

I suggest you check the parameters that determines the association between predicted boxed and ground truth annotations. Moreover, look at the parameters of your "anchors": these parameters determines the scale and aspect ratios of the predicted boxes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. In my case, the dataset has very few data and only 3 classes and there is no `__background__` class. This Pytorch implementation is quite complex, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to tweak parameters related to anchor boxes and ground truth associations.

Comment: @RakihthaRR you should have background class.

Comment: Oh, I see. What objects should fall under the background class? The classes I have are not present in COCO anyway.

Comment: @RakihthaRR background are predicted boxes that do not cover any of the other classes